# iOS - animation and performance?

Tags: ios, core-animation

- Does setting shouldRasterize to a CALayer apply the same behavior to its subLayers?
- My app animates the main UINavigationController in order to display a menu which is hidden behind the UINavigationController. Is it a bad idea to set rasterizing for every layer of my ViewControllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShouldRasterize is a property of [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), not UIView, and yes, it does affect sub-*layers*.

Rasterization draws things offscreen and then composites them onscreen, which is beautiful and extremely useful for shadows, otherwise it's not that useful.